# Replace zeros with NAs based on same ID used in each dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, match

I would like to replace the zeros with NAs based on the same ID labels used in 2 different dataframes. Specifically, my first dataframe (df1) is longer than the second (df2) and present some zeros in "Value" that have to be replaced with values found in Value2 (df2) by matching ID (from df1) with ID2 (from df2).
I list the 2 dataframes below:

```
ID <- c("A1", "B1", "C1","D1","E1","F1","H1")  # and more
Value<- c(0,3,0,7,10,15,0)                     # and more

df1 <- data.frame(ID, Value)


ID2<-c("A1","C1","H1")
Value2<-c(NA, NA, NA)
df2 <- data.frame(ID2, Value2)
```

I tried functions like aggregate and match but without success, any help would be appreciated!

Thank you,
Michela

Answer (score 0):

This example code may be helpful:

##### 1. Create sample datasets

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A1", "B1", "C1","D1","E1","F1","H1"),  
                  Value = c(0,0,0,7,10,15,0))                  # note 1

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("A1","C1","H1"),
                  Value = c(NA, NA, NA))
```

Note 1: Please note that I have changed B1 from 3 to 0 for testing later.

##### 2. Replace 0s with NAs only when the ID in df1 corresponds to the IDs of df2

```
df1 |> 
  mutate(Value = case_when(
    ID %in% df2$ID ~ as.numeric(NA),
    TRUE ~ Value
  ))
```

You get:

```
  ID     Value
1 A1      NA
2 B1       0           # note 2
3 C1      NA
4 D1       7
5 E1      10
6 F1      15
7 H1      NA
```

Note 2: Recall that B1 is from df1 with 0, as long as ID from df1 is not in df2, their value will be kept, otherwise their values will be changed to NAs.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi @Grasshopper_NZ, many thanks for your feedback but I have a doubt: in dataframe 1 I may have some zeros that need to remain zeros: with this code, I will change all zeros in NAs, and this is not what I have to do.

Comment: No worries - Do you want to keep some 0s from df1, and replace the rest with values from df2? If so, could you specify in what condition 0s need to be reserved? I will think about how to achieve this.

Comment: I need to replace 0s with NAs only with the ID in df1 corresponds to the IDs of df2. I have tried this code too: ID <- c("A", "B", "C","C", "D","D","E","F","G","H","I","L","M","N")
Value<- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
df <- data.frame(ID, Value)


ID2 <- c("N", "B", "C","A")
Value2<- c(999,999,999,999)
df2 <- data.frame(ID2, Value2)

Comment: I need to replace 0s with NAs only when the ID in df1 corresponds to the IDs of df2. In df1 the same id can be repeated multiple times (all of them have to be replaced with NA),  I have tried this code using 999 instead of NA (to eventually change it later), but no success.

Comment: Got it, I think I have a solution to test with you - will update the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution: that's what I did.
I created a dataframe (df) which contains some values that have to be replaced:

```
ID <- c("A", "B", "C","C", "D","D","E","F","G","H","I","L","M","N")
Value<- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
df <- data.frame(ID, Value)
df
```

I created the second dataframe (df2), which contains values (here NA) to be replaced in df by reference IDs:

```
ID <- c("N", "B", "C","A")
Value <-c(NA,NA,NA,NA)
df2<-data.frame(ID, Value)
df2
```

I used the `library(data.table)` and coded as follows:

```
setDT(df)[df2, Value := i.Value , on =.(ID)]

> df
    ID Value
 1:  A    NA
 2:  B    NA
 3:  C    NA
 4:  C    NA
 5:  D     0
 6:  D     0
 7:  E     1
 8:  F     1
 9:  G     1
10:  H     0
11:  I     0
12:  L     1
13:  M     1
14:  N    NA
```